# Interrupting Amida for a Mitzvah

Tags: tefilla, shemoneh-esrei, mitzvah, vayera, hachnasat-orchim-guests

Avraham leaves Hashem to deal with guests in Vayera - because welcoming guests is greater than Kabolas Pnei HaSh'china.

Does that mean we can interrupt our Shmoneh Esrei to do mitzvahs? At least to do hachnosas orchim?

Comment: do you have a source that tefila is Kabolas Pnei HaSh'china?

Comment: @ray Seems pretty similar. Both involve you talking you talking to God

Comment: right but avraham's was prophecy,i.e. a 2 way conversation and he asked permission.

Comment: Well, we don't interrupt even to greet a king (somewhere in the early dafim of B'rachot).

Comment: There was no 3amidho during abrohom obinu's 3alow hasholom time. It was all ta7anuuneem n baqoshoth. Which is not mandatory and it would seem like his ta7anuuneem were intertwined with his prophecies. Thereby it was a "real" conversation through prayer n prophecy at the same time.

Answer (score 2):

[Kovaitz Heoros Ubeurim](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=29465&st=&pgnum=8&hilite=) asks this question and concludes that only for someone like Avraham who for him Hachnasas Orchim was "Umnoso" would be permitted to interrupt Tefila for Hachnasas Orchim, however for others it is not permitted.

Comment: interesting. so what are we supposed to learn from the statement of chazal that hachnasat orchim is greater etc..